# Linking two pieces of code in Python

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to write a code that watches a specific file in a certain directory, and then when the file is updated my program tells me it has updated and then reads from this updated file and outputs a personalised response.

To watch the file, I use watchdog and that works fine by itself. To read from the file, I have written a really simple code to get it to read the number in the text file, then use if-elif-else statements to get the desired output. However, I struggle with linking the 2 pieces of code together i.e. I would like the wathdog script to watch the file, then when it updates trigger the next part of the code that reads the file watchdog was looking at and give the desired output.

I'm really stuck, would anyone be able to help me out?

EDIT:

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.event import FileSystemEventHandler

class Myhandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
      def on_modified(self, event):
      print("Got it!")

if __name__== "__main__":
     event_handler = MyHandler()
     observer = Observer()
     observer.schedule(event_handler, path = 'My path here', recursive=False)

try:
   while True:
             time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
   observer.stop()
observer.join()
```

That's my watchdog code that watches the file for when it is updated.

```
f=open("MyFile.txt", encoding='utf-8-sig')
g=f.read()
print(g)
num=int(g)
if num = 10:
     r = open("Response.txt", "w")
     r.write("Bla")
     r.close()
elif num = 20
     r = open("Response.txt", "w")
     r.write("Bla")
     r.close()
```

And so on with all the other options. This second part is the part that writes a new text file based on what is written on the file that is being watched.

What I would like to do is have watchdog (first part of the code) watch a file, then when it is updated, trigger the second part of the code to read from that file and give the designated output (second part of the code) I just can't figure out how to link the two! I though putting the second part of the code in the 'if' section of the first code, but it didn't work.

Comment: Please provide a minimum verifiable example code of what you're trying to put together.

Comment: why don’t you just put the code into `on_modified`?

Comment: Where would I pass it exactly? Would it replace the self, event or add as another argument?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do something like this?

```
import time
while True:
    Text=open('MyFile.txt','r')
    fileText=Text.read()
    Text.close()
    newText=fileText
    while fileText==newText:
        time.sleep(5)
        Text=open('MyFile.txt','r')
        newText=Text.read()
        Text.close()
    f=open("MyFile.txt", encoding='utf-8-sig')
    g=f.read()
    print(g)
    num=int(g)
    if num == 10:
         r = open("Response.txt", "w")
         r.write("Bla")
         r.close()
    elif num == 20:
         r = open("Response.txt", "w")
         r.write("Bla")
         r.close()
```

Comment: Maybe...What would I put in instead of Original text? I get an error message when I run it with originalText and also when I put the name of the txt file I'm reading from

Comment: Hmmm it seems to still not work. I will write to the file and update it, but then it doesn't progress to the next part.

Comment: Nah still no dice mate, should I be specifying what the newText file is, or just leave it as newText=''

Comment: What error does it run? Does it just do nothing? You should only need to change out the MyFile.txt.

Comment: It seems like it runs, since I have to hit ctrl+c to force it to stop. I use another thing to write to the text file, and the text file definitely gets written to and modified, but then the f=open(MyText), g=f.read() still doesn't seem to work

Comment: Try putting a print ("test") statement before the f=open("MyFile.txt", encoding='utf-8-sig'). It should not be a part of the second while statement. If it prints, there is a problem with the code that you wrote, and you should probably create a new post for that. If it doesn't print, tell me, and I'll try to fix my code.

Comment: Yeah I don't get any print readout when I have it in the same indentation as "while" and "f-open" for example.

Comment: I'll try to fix whatever I did. When do you need to solve this by? I may be able to give the answer tonight, but it may be tomorrow.

Comment: No rush :) This is just a fun little code I'm trying to get up and running for my gaming streams and such. Does the f=open statement need to be in line with the second while word?

Comment: Cool, I'll get you an answer by the end of tomorrow or fail trying. This is a fun puzzle! The f=open statement should only be aligned with the first while statement.

Comment: Funny story about coding when you are tired. I accidently set the code so it only executes the code if the file is the same. I'll edit this, then you can see if the other part works. Turns out that this wasn't a big fix. :)

Comment: Yeah it still doesn't trigger the next part of the code! The part I wrote still works fine, how would I test to see if your part is working?

Comment: That is weird! The code seems to work when I try it. What I did to test it is to replace the second part of the code, from the "f=open" to the "r.close" with a statement "print('test')".  Then I made a text file called MyFile.txt that was in the same folder as the program.

Comment: I opened the text file and wrote in it "testing123".Then I ran the program. I let it run for a few seconds to make sure it wasn't crashing, and then, I opened MyFile.txt and changed the text to "testing" and saved it. Then I went back to my program console and it had printed "test". That seemed to indicate that my code had worked.

Comment: Yeah I think your code does work, and mine does too. They just don't work with each other haha. It's almost as if there needs to be an if statement somewhere after your code (or in it) saying if "the text changes" then f=open(MyText) bla bla

Comment: Lol, well I think that this phenomenon of both parts not working together surpasses my Python knowledge, but there are a couple of things I noticed about the code. Try my new edit; if it doesn't work, then I have failed trying, and I wish you the best of luck in this and all of your future Python endeavors.